# pthread_join() causing seg fault

Tags: c, pthreads

So I've looked over about every issue i could fine both on stack and many other sources. While i was able to fix some issues and add some extra testing it still hasnt resolved my issue. The program is set up with mergesort.c, which calls the functions, mergesortTest.c, which tests my functions. The serial implementation works just fine. I got past the issue with my initial creates. However, now that im trying to join them I'm getting a seg fault. Ive used both valgrind and gdb to test it and its on my join. Though i cant print out an error message since it causes a seg fault and shuts down my program. Ive made sure to try and allocate proper space. However ill post my code and the output of gdb in hopes someone can help me with this.

```
                            **mergesort.c**


#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAX 100000000
#define MAX_CORE 4

// function prototypes
void serial_mergesort(int A[], int p, int r); 
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r);
void insertion_sort(int A[], int p, int r);
void *pthread_mergesort(void *arg); 

struct mergeS
{
    int numElements;
    int *A;
    int level;
    int Max_Level;
};

const int INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD = 100; //based on trial and error


/*
 * insertion_sort(int A[], int p, int r):
 *
 * description: Sort the section of the array A[p..r].
 */
void insertion_sort(int A[], int p, int r) 
{
    int j;

    for (j=p+1; j<=r; j++) {
        int key = A[j];
        int i = j-1;
        while ((i > p-1) && (A[i] > key)) { 
            A[i+1] = A[i];
            i--;
        }
        A[i+1] = key;
    }
}



/*
 * serial_mergesort(int A[], int p, int r):
 *
 * description: Sort the section of the array A[p..r].
 */
void serial_mergesort(int A[], int p, int r) 
{
    if (r-p+1 <= INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD)  {
            insertion_sort(A,p,r);
    } else {
        int q = (p+r)/2;
        serial_mergesort(A, p, q);
        serial_mergesort(A, q+1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}

/*
 * pthread_mergesort(void *arg)
 *
 * description:Sorts based off levels
 *
 */



void *pthread_mergesort(void *arg) 
{   

    struct mergeS *threader = (struct mergeS*) arg;


    int i = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int level = (threader)->level;
    printf("level: %d\n",level);
    int numElements = threader->numElements;
    int Max_Level = threader->Max_Level;
    int *A = threader->A;

    if(Max_Level == 1)
    {   
        serial_mergesort(A,1,numElements + 1);
        return NULL;
    }

    int low = level * (numElements/Max_Level) + 1;
    int high =((level + 1) * ((numElements/Max_Level)));

    pthread_t *tids = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * 2);
    struct mergeS *merger = (struct mergeS*) malloc(sizeof(struct mergeS) * 2);
    int error = 0;

    if(level < Max_Level - 1)
    {
        for(i = 0;i < 2; i ++)
        {
            printf("for loop\n");
            merger[i].numElements = numElements/(i + 1);
            merger[i].level = threader->level + 1;
            merger[i].Max_Level = threader->Max_Level;
            merger[i].A = threader->A;
            if((error = pthread_create(&tids[i],NULL,pthread_mergesort,(void*)&merger[i])) == 0)
            {
                printf("thread failed\n");
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

    printf("error: %d\n",error);

    }

    serial_mergesort(A,low,high);
    int j = 0;

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("for level: %d\n",threader->level);
            printf("join = %d\n", j);
            if((error = pthread_join(tids[j],NULL)) != 0)
            {
                printf("error: %d\n",error);
            }
        }
    }

    merge(A,low,(high/2) + 1,high);
    free(merger);
    free (tids);

    return NULL;

}

/*
 * merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r):
 *
 * description: Merge two sorted sequences A[p..q] and A[q+1..r] 
 *              and place merged output back in array A. Uses extra
 *              space proportional to A[p..r].
 */     
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) 
{
    int *B = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (r-p+1));

    int i = p;
    int j = q+1;
    int k = 0;
    int l;

    // as long as both lists have unexamined elements
    // this loop keeps executing.
    while ((i <= q) && (j <= r)) {
        if (A[i] < A[j]) {
            B[k] = A[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            B[k] = A[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // now only at most one list has unprocessed elements.

    if (i <= q) { 
        // copy remaining elements from the first list
        for (l=i; l<=q; l++) {
            B[k] = A[l];
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        // copy remaining elements from the second list
        for (l=j; l<=r; l++) {
            B[k] = A[l];
            k++;
        }
    }

    // copy merged output from array B back to array A
    k=0;
    for (l=p; l<=r; l++) {
        A[l] = B[k];
        k++;
    }

    free(B);
}
```

end of file

```
                       **mergesortTest.c**

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_THREAD 4
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// function prototypes
int check_if_sorted(int A[], int n);
void generate_random_array(int A[], int n, int seed);
void serial_mergesort(int A[], int p, int r); 
void *pthread_mergesort(void *arg); 
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r);
void insertion_sort(int A[], int p, int r);
double getMilliSeconds();

// Struct
struct mergeS
{
    int numElements;
    int *A;
    int level;
    int Max_Level;
};


/*
 * generate_random_array(int A[], int n, int seed):
 *
 * description: Generate random integers in the range [0,RANGE]
 *              and store in A[1..n]
 */

#define RANGE 1000000

void generate_random_array(int A[], int n, int seed)
{
    int i;

    srandom(seed);
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        A[i] = random()%RANGE;
    }
}


/*
 * check_if_sorted(int A[], int n):
 *
 * description: returns TRUE if A[1..n] are sorted in nondecreasing order
 *              otherwise returns FALSE
 */     

int check_if_sorted(int A[], int n) 
{
    int i=0;

    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if (A[i] > A[i+1]) {
        printf("%d > %d\n",A[i],A[i+1]);
        printf("i: %d\n",i);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}




int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("argc = %d\n",argc); 
    int n;
    int Max_Level = 4;
    int flag = 1;
    int seed;

    if (argc == 1) { // there must be at least one command-line argument
            printf("Default: Input Size = 100000000     levels: 4\n");
            printf("Usage: executable    input size     number of levels\n");
            n = 100000000;      
            seed = 4;
            flag = 0;
    }

    if (argc == 2 && flag == 1) {
        printf("Default: Threads: 4\n");
        printf("Usage: executable    input size     number of levels\n");
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        Max_Level = 4;
        seed = 4;
    }

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        Max_Level = atoi(argv[2]);
        seed = Max_Level;
    }

    if(Max_Level > 15)
    {
        printf("To many levels. Setting to 4\n");
        Max_Level = 4;
        seed = Max_Level;
    }


    int *A = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (n+1)); // n+1 since we are using A[1]..A[n]

    // generate random input

    generate_random_array(A,n,seed);

    double start_time;
    double sorting_time;

    // sort the input (and time it)
    start_time = getMilliSeconds();
    serial_mergesort(A,1,n);
    sorting_time = getMilliSeconds() - start_time;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                               Start of parallel                                         //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    int *B = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (n+1)); // n+1 since we are using A[1]..A[n]

    //int i;
    double p_start_time;
    double p_sorting_time;

    struct mergeS *threader = (struct mergeS*) malloc(sizeof(struct mergeS));

    generate_random_array(B,n,seed);

    // sort the input with threads (and time it)
    p_start_time = getMilliSeconds();
        threader[0].numElements = n;
        threader[0].level = 0;
        threader[0].Max_Level = Max_Level;
        threader[0].A = B;
        pthread_mergesort(threader);


    printf("sorted\n");
    /*for(i = 0;i < n + 1;i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("B[%d]: %d\n",i,B[i]);
    }
    printf("B:[%d] = %d\n",999,B[999]);
    */

    p_sorting_time = getMilliSeconds() - p_start_time;

    // print results if correctly sorted otherwise cry foul and exit
    if (check_if_sorted(A,n)) {
        printf("Serial: Sorting %d elements took %4.2lf seconds.\n", n,  sorting_time/1000.0);
    } else { 
        printf("%s: sorting failed!!!!\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (check_if_sorted(B,n)) {
        printf("Threaded: Sorting %d elements took %4.2lf seconds.\n", n,  p_sorting_time/1000.0);
    } else { 
        printf("%s: parallel sorting failed!!!!\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(threader);
    free(A);
    free(B);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

end of file

```
                    **GBD error report and code output**

[rutgerluther@onyxnode72 multi-threaded]$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./mergesort 1000 2
==5636== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5636== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5636== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5636== Command: ./mergesort 1000 2
==5636== 
argc = 3
level: 0
for loop
thread failed
for loop
thread failed
error: 0
sorted
Serial: Sorting 1000 elements took 0.00 seconds.
993090 > 163007
i: 500
./mergesort: parallel sorting failed!!!!
==5636== 
==5636== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5636==     in use at exit: 9,152 bytes in 5 blocks
==5636==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 25 frees, 33,216 bytes allocated
==5636== 
==5636== 1,120 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 4
==5636==    at 0x4C2B9B5: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==5636==    by 0x40128C4: _dl_allocate_tls (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==5636==    by 0x4E3E7FB: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==5636==    by 0x400E88: pthread_mergesort (mergesort.c:114)
==5636==    by 0x400B00: main (mergesortTest.c:145)
==5636== 
==5636== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5636==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636==      possibly lost: 1,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==5636==    still reachable: 8,032 bytes in 3 blocks
==5636==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==5636== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==5636== 
==5636== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5636== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[rutgerluther@onyxnode72 multi-threaded]$ gdb ./mergesort
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-110.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/RutgerLuther/RutgerLuther@u.boisestate.edu/backpack/CS453-1-f18/p2/multi-threaded/mergesort...done.
(gdb) b 130
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400abd: file mergesortTest.c, line 130.
(gdb) r 1000 2
Starting program: /home/RutgerLuther/RutgerLuther@u.boisestate.edu/backpack/CS453-1-f18/p2/multi-threaded/./mergesort 1000 2
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
argc = 3

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fffffffcf98) at mergesortTest.c:135
135             struct mergeS *threader = (struct mergeS*) malloc(sizeof(struct mergeS));
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
(gdb) n
137             generate_random_array(B,n,seed);
(gdb) 
140             p_start_time = getMilliSeconds();
(gdb) 
141                     threader[0].numElements = n;
(gdb) 
142                     threader[0].level = 0;
(gdb) 
143                     threader[0].Max_Level = Max_Level;
(gdb) 
144                     threader[0].A = B;
(gdb) 
145                     pthread_mergesort(threader);
(gdb) 
level: 0
for loop
[New Thread 0x7ffff77f1700 (LWP 5892)]
thread failed
for loop
level: 1
for level: 1
join = 0
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ff0700 (LWP 5893)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff77f1700 (LWP 5892)]
0x00007ffff7bc7f01 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb)
```

end of file

```
                              **Valgrind report**

[rutgerluther@onyxnode72 multi-threaded]$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./mergesort 1000 2
==5636== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5636== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5636== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5636== Command: ./mergesort 1000 2
==5636== 
argc = 3
level: 0
for loop
thread failed
for loop
thread failed
error: 0
sorted
Serial: Sorting 1000 elements took 0.00 seconds.
993090 > 163007
i: 500
./mergesort: parallel sorting failed!!!!
==5636== 
==5636== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5636==     in use at exit: 9,152 bytes in 5 blocks
==5636==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 25 frees, 33,216 bytes allocated
==5636== 
==5636== 1,120 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 4
==5636==    at 0x4C2B9B5: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==5636==    by 0x40128C4: _dl_allocate_tls (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==5636==    by 0x4E3E7FB: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==5636==    by 0x400E88: pthread_mergesort (mergesort.c:114)
==5636==    by 0x400B00: main (mergesortTest.c:145)
==5636== 
==5636== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5636==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636==      possibly lost: 1,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==5636==    still reachable: 8,032 bytes in 3 blocks
==5636==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5636== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==5636== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==5636== 
==5636== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5636== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[rutgerluther@onyxnode72 multi-threaded]$
```

end of file

Im running this giving it only a 1000 elements and only using 2 threads. Though the issue still happens with any threads more than 1.
Ive read the man pages and looked at other exmaples and previous cases where i used this and class mates did. But i still cant figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

If changed some things and pthread is creating correctly. This is stepping into the function. I dont know what the value of tids[0] should be. But the elements in the array are random numbers.

```
                        **mergesort.c function call on tids**
level: 1
116                             if((error = pthread_create(&tids[i],NULL,pthread_mergesort,(void*)&merger[i])) != 0)
(gdb) info tids
Undefined info command: "tids".  Try "help info".
(gdb) print tids[0]
$2 = 140737345689344
(gdb) print &tids
Address requested for identifier "tids" which is in register $r14
(gdb) print *tids
$3 = 140737345689344
(gdb) n
thread failed
for level: 1
join = 0
117                             {
(gdb) print tids
$4 = (pthread_t *) 0x604f90
(gdb) print tids[0]
$5 = 140737345689344
(gdb)
```

Comment: It looks pretty much that you had not initialized `tid` data. Check you r 'level'

Comment: ya the guy below mentioned that as welll just with more detail thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `tids` array contains uninitialized data if the branch `if(level < Max_Level - 1)` is not taken. You need to call `pthread_join` only if you called `pthread_create` successfully.

Comment: Ya my threads are failing. i was checking for the wrong return value. Ill look up why they arent properly being created thank you.

Comment: So i added a checker in and it is creating the threads but im still having the same issue. Ill edit the code

Comment: @RutgerLuther Not the solution to your problem, but it’s good practice to initialize your arrays either to sensible default values or to zero. For a static array, `static pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS] = {};` will do it. For a dynamic array, `pthread_t *const tids = (pthread_t*)calloc( num_threads, sizeof(pthread_t) );`. This makes any bugs caused by not initializing the array reproducible, although not necessarily portable.

Comment: thanks though why is it good to fill it in? Just basic intialization practice?

Comment: @Davislor: There is no "null thread id" value, so that's not particularly helpful in this case. It might crash slightly more predictably, but the real issue is that OP needs to avoid using variables that have not been filled with *valid* values.

Comment: @R.. I agree. As I said, this doesn’t solve the problem, but it’s a very good habit to get into and will make a lot of other problems more reproducible.

Comment: @RutgerLuther The main benefit that I’ve seen from it, personally, is that it makes bugs a lot easier to reproduce and spot. If your value is `0`, and you never update it before use, that’s *always* going going to be the same invalid value (`0`, `-1`, `BAD_VALUE`, etc.) and not some arbitrary junk that might or might not work. If it fails, it will fail the same way every time. And, when checking a value in the debugger, the value will look *obviously* wrong. A garbage value might not look like garbage, but `0x00000000` is blatantly a null pointer.

Comment: @RutgerLuther On the other hand, it’s possible you might suppress a compiler warning about a variable being used before initialization, by making it look as if you did that on purpose.

Comment: Yes, what @Davislor said. I consider initializing variables with non-meaningful values harmful because it suppresses the ability for compiler warnings/static analysis to tell you you have a bug. An initial value is *meaningful* if it's the correct default value to have in code paths where it's otherwise not set.

Comment: @R.. Another approach is to turn any complex initializer into a phi function, which is what modern compilers do when converting to Static Single Assignment form anyway. That is, `pthread_t* const tids = initialize_tids();` Or make it a pointer to `pthread_t[MAX]`. In this case, though, the static analyzer can’t help you, so I’d personally prefer `calloc()` to `malloc()`.

Comment: @R.. If you initialize to a known invalid value, you can also use assertions to ensure that your variables no longer have that invalid value, which you cannot do if they’re uninitialized. (Checking them would then be undefined behavior in and of itself.)